# Maven Error in eclipse build

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven

i have error

> " [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:dbunit-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-3:operation
>   (default-cli) on project person: Error executing database operation:
>   CLEAN_INSERT: No suitable Driver for
>   ${hibernate.connection.url}&sessionVariables=FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 ->
>   [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors,
>   re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X
>   switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more
>   information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the
>   following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
>   "

what the solutions about error ?
please help

Comment: Is mysql database connector part of your project/plugin dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Property `hibernate.connection.url` is not configured needed by DBUnit to run your Tests.

Comment: i have hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cimande?autoReconnect=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull

how to configured that?

Comment: run maven with -Dhibernate.connection.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cimande?autoReconnect=true&‌​zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"